# Error in dtd validation : A ')' is required in the declaration of element type "Bibliography"

Tags: xml, dtd

The error comes up on my editix editor for the first line below. Just cannot see why a ) is needed.

```
<!ELEMENT Bibliography (Conference paper,Book,Book chapter,Journal article)>
<!ATTLIST Author Title Year CDATA#REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Conference paper (Author,Title,URL)>
<!ELEMENT Author #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT Title #PCDATA>
<!ELEMENT URL #PCDATA>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have an element named `Conference paper`. You can't have spaces in names. See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name) for more details. Specifically the definitions of [NameStartChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) and [NameChar](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar).

Maybe use `ConferencePaper`, `Conference_paper`, `Conference-paper`, etc.

You'll have the same issues with `Book chapter` and `Journal article`.

I also noticed these additional issues:

- The declaration `<!ATTLIST Author Title Year CDATA#REQUIRED>` is invalid. See [Attribute-List Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#attdecls) for a description of how the ATTLIST should be structured.
- You need to surround `#PCDATA` in parentheses (the content model) in the element declarations for `Author`, `Title`, and `URL`. (Like `<!ELEMENT Author (#PCDATA)>`) See [Element Type Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#elemdecls) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is actually my first attempt to code and these are probably a newbie's mistake

Comment: @tsinasky - You're very welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.